# Override Public Readonly property

Tags: vb.net

Having a bit of a brain fart, right before bed.  But i have the need to remap a `ReadOnly Property` from one name to a specified name i want.

I figured i could do

```
Public Readonly Property DocName as String
  Get
    Return Mybase.Name
  End Get
End Property
```

And yes i am trying to remap the Name Property for an XMLDocument object.  Just want to make sure that as long as i declare this property and then type:

```
Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Name As String
    Get
        Return SomeValue
    End Get
End Property
```

I will be good togo?  I know i will get the `method has multiple definitions with identical signatures` message, which brings me to my 2nd Question:

How do i prevent the `Multiple Signatures` error message from popping up with this type of declaration?

Unless i am missing some declaration attribute for this type of override.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Shadows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3wytf6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to accomplish this:

```
Public Class A
    Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
        Get
            Return "Name"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class B
    Inherits A

    Public ReadOnly Property DocName As String
        Get
            Return MyBase.Name
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Name As String
        Get
            Return "SomeValue"
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: I actually want the Deriving class to use the `Name` Property, if possible, and remap the Base Class to `DocName`

Comment: its fine if its not possible, just would be nice if i could :)

Comment: Ah, I see what you're trying to do now. Shadows should actually work for this scenario.

Comment: ok so just `Shadows ReadOnly Property Name As String` for the property i plan on using and then just declare secondary Property/Method to return the `MyBase.Name`?

Comment: Yep. I just updated the answer to show two classes implementing this behavior.